# Не изменяются данные в сервисе

Tags: angularjs

Не могу понять. Каким образом работает this в сервисах и связь данных с контроллером?

У меня есть сервис запрашивающий данные

```
app.factory('foldersResource', function($resource){
    return {
        create: $resource('/create-folder')
    };
});
```

В другом сервисе определяется функция получающая данные и переменная, куда эти данные сохраняются

```
app.factory('foldersActionSrv', foldersActionSrv);
foldersActionSrv.$inject = ['openModalSrv', 'foldersResource'];

function foldersActionSrv(openModalSrv, foldersResource) {
    return {
        folders: [],
        getFolders: function () {
            this.folders = foldersResource.create.query();
        }
    }
}
```

В контроллере я вызываю метод получающий данные. А так же присваиваю в переменную все полученные до этого данные.

```
foldersActionSrv.getFolders();
vm.folders = foldersActionSrv.folders;
```

В таком виде все отлично сохраняется и при изменении данных в folders в сервисе, также происходят изменения в контроллере и представлении. Все хорошо. Но! Когда я получаю данные таким способом

```
function foldersActionSrv(openModalSrv, foldersResource) {
    return {
        folders: [],
        getFolders: function () {
            var that = this;
            foldersResource.create.query({}, function(result){
                that.folders = result;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

то в folders ничего не сохраняется. В консоль переменная folders выводится, но записать я в нее ничего не могу. Может есть другой способ решить подобную задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не проверял но думаю заработает :)

```
app.factory('foldersActionSrv', function foldersActionSrv(openModalSrv, foldersResource) {

 var service = {}

 service.folders = [];

 service.getFolders = function(){
    foldersResource.create.query({}, function(result){
        service.folders = result;
    });     
 }

 return service;

});
```

**UPDATE**

пример сервиса

```
app.factory('CustomersActions', ['Customers', function(Customers){

 var service = {}

 service.customers = [];

 service.getCustomers = function(){
    var query = Customers.query(function(result){
        service.customers = result;
    });     

    return query;
 }

 return service;
}]);
```

контроллера

```
var cust = CustomersActions;
cust.getCustomers().$promise.then(function(){
    $scope.customers = cust.customers;
})
```

получается мы теперь ожидаем когда данные "придут" а потом уже заносим их в скоуп.

**UPDATE 2**

в общем происходит этому потому, что это особенность JS
когда грузиться контроллер и вызывается

```
vm.folders = foldersActionSrv.folders;
```

ожидается, что объект передается по ссылке и любые изменения в

```
foldersActionSrv.folders
```

приведут к изменениям в

```
vm.folders
```

так оно и есть, до тех пор пока не будет выполнена

```
getFolders
```

где произойдет

```
that.folders = result;
```

после этого будет ссылаться уже на другой объект(result который), а

```
vm.folders
```

на другой

вот самый простой пример

```
test1 = {a:1};
test2 = test1;
test3 = {a:2};
test2 = test3;
```

в итоге получиться

```
test1 != test2
test2 === test3
```

Думаю понятно объяснил))

Comment: Не работает. Зато я заметил, что данные в массив сохраняются если я push-у их туда. А если присваиваю, то не сохраняются. Где, где же тут логика!?

Comment: все таки проверить надо было сразу)) изменил ответ

Comment: Да, с $promise получилось. Даже сервис старый не пришлось менять. Оставил как был в самом начальном виде.